How to emulate LEAD() functionality inside a row-based trigger function?
given: postgresql v16, pgAdmin 4
seeking: update several columns on same row with future (or past) data in other rows, but from inside a trigger function.
want: use future/past values from the same column to compute and insert/update values on the 'working' row.
I have sadly found that a row-based Function called by a Trigger for insert/updates cannot access other rows via LEAD or LAG. Assuming that is true...
The trigger is:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_fxx
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON data.d_xyz
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION data.update_fxx_columns();

[BEGIN explanation of calculations, which is not the issue. The issue is simply accessing other future/past rows. Some like to see a use case, so it is presented solely for them. An "END" will indicate the end of this section]

This is all your standard stock data storage example.



symbol_date
symbol_adj
f01
f02
fn...




1999-11-01
4.969
1.011873616
0.987723888
...


1999-11-02
5.028
0.976133652
0.964399364



1999-11-03
4.908
0.98797881
1.085574572



1999-11-04
4.849
1.098783254




1999-11-05
5.328






f01 is simply the next day's value divided by the current one, f02 is from 2 days in future, etc. To make it clearer:
We are processing an INSERT or UPDATE to the top row, date: 11/1/1999. We use the current value of 4.969 and the value of the same column tomorrow to determine the value for f01 on the same row by dividing:
symbol_adj (today + 1) / symbol_adj (today)
or... 5.028 / 4.969 and UPDATE column f01 on the same row with that value: 1.011873616.
The f02 (future 2 days) is 0.987723888, etc. UPDATEs are always to the same row that the function was called for-BUT it needs future values to do so. In fact, in plain SQL, this works well outside a ROW-based Trigger Function:
SELECT symbol_name, symbol_date, symbol_adj,  
            ROUND(data.f_pct_difference(symbol_adj, (LEAD(symbol_adj, 1) OVER (ORDER BY symbol_date DESC)))::numeric, 3) as f01,
            ROUND(data.f_pct_difference(symbol_adj, (LEAD(symbol_adj, 2) OVER (ORDER BY symbol_date DESC)))::numeric, 3) as f02,
            ROUND(data.f_pct_difference(symbol_adj, (LEAD(symbol_adj, 3) OVER (ORDER BY symbol_date DESC)))::numeric, 3) as f03,
        [...]

...but this doesn't work in the body of the Trigger Function.
I wonder if these is a way to EXECUTE the above SQL in the function instead of being a part of the function itself...?
FYI: function data.f_pct_difference() is one I wrote to try to keep things cleaner, but it does what you see above.

[END semi-related 'use case']
The Problem
I've been at this for an embarrassingly long time, and all I can think of is emulating LEAD() by doing a SELECT INTO query, but using the next snippet, all I get is 0.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.update_fxx_columns()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
    AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    rowx record;
    resnum int;
BEGIN
    SET client_min_messages = NOTICE;
    FOR rowx IN SELECT symbol_name, symbol_date, symbol_adj
        FROM data.xyz WHERE symbol_date < NEW.symbol_date
            ORDER BY symbol_date DESC LIMIT 5 LOOP
            NEW.f01 := rowx.symbol_adj::numeric;
            resnum = resnum + 1;
        END LOOP;
    NEW.f02 := resnum;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

It is likely that there is a way to use LEAD or LAG the way they were meant to be from inside a trigger function, but if they cannot access other rows, it would explain earlier failures. I may have to resort to dynamic queries, but I've had little luck. TIA
[code has been slightly obfuscated to reduce distractions]

you should use a after trigger not a before, because then the table is already changed and you can run LEAD or LAG as you please with the now updated/inserted data, it will still be a hell of a function to update the correct columns , but doable as far as my brain try to process the concept

Concurrency is an issue, your trigger function can't see other new records that are concurrently inserted. These inserts also trigger your function, and can't see the other fresh but uncommitted data either. Without concurrency, by locking the table, you might be fine.

@nbk I tried AFTER, and what it does is create a loop. Because the function itself UPDATEs a row, it triggers another instance of itself. The trigger fires on an UPDATE. You see the results of a BEFORE after  subsequent SELECT.

you neeed to put the f01... in another table and use teh date as linking the both. so that you can run over all inserted data and change the necessary row in the new table for every change you make. of course you need a table lock to update a lot of rows, and that could lead to deadlock,   so you should have a fast ssd to hold the data
